# How to connect bluetooth with default pin "0000"-Unable to pair

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

To connect a Bluetooth device with embedded device,I want user's click on discovered device and auto pair with `0000` pin (No need for confirmation and also important `0000` passkey), not with creating bond with passkeys,I don't have any connection related issue
I found following code I am not sure its working or not also don't know on how to pair Device(phone) to another device(Embedded device) with `pin="0000"` in this code??

Here is some part of code for connectivity.

**OnItemClicklistner on discoverd(scanned ) devices**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");
        registerReceiver(mPairingRequestReceiver, filter);

    }
```

**This is my pairing Receiver for connection with `0000` pin**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mPairingRequestReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST)) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //   int pin=intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
                //the pin in case you need to accept for an specific pin
                String pin="0000";
                Log.d(TAG, "Start Auto Pairing. PIN = " + intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY",0));
                byte[] pinBytes;
                // pinBytes = (""+pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                pinBytes = pin.getBytes();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    device.setPin(pinBytes);
                    device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurs when trying to auto pair");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Note : Creat bond is working here.  I dont want to creat bond  just on click Item  and connect to embedded device with 0000 pin.... Thank you..**